# Get zoom to input value Google Maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get map's zoom value, after searching an address, or dragging marker or zoom change anyway, I add here all of my codes html, css and js.

There are a lot of firms in my website and my aim is they can set your firms place with searching and dragging marker to their firms addresses.

Now with my code i can search places, and i can get coordinates, also after search when users move the marker (drag) i can get coordinates, however i can not get zoom value, but i want to get zoom value of map.

You can see a preview of my project here.

[image]

As you see at the picture i can get lat and lng value but i want to get also zoom value, can you help me to add some code to my javascript code.

```js
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28,32);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 
 
   // document.getElementById('zoom').value = map.getZoom();
 
}
  
function updateCoordinates(latlng)
{
  if(latlng) 
  {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = latlng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = latlng.lng();
 
  }
}
 
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            updateCoordinates(results[0].geometry.location);
            if (marker) marker.setMap(null);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable: true,
   });
          
      
   
   
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
                updateCoordinates(marker.getPosition());
            });

        } else {
            alert("Lutfen bir yer yaziniz: " + status);
        }
    });
}






    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
    }
```

```css
#map_canvas {
 width:100%;
 min-width:300px;
 min-height:300px;

}
.adres-map { min-height:65px; margin-top:10px;}
.latlng-map { min-height:90px; margin-top:10px;}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<form role="form" >

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Arama butonu ile firmanıza yakınlaşıp kırmızı baloncuğu firmanızın bulunduğu yere <strong>taşıyınız.</strong>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Arama yapmadan kırmızı balon <strong>görünmeyecektir</strong>, Enlem ve boylam otomatik yazacaktır.
 </div>



  <div class="adres-map alert alert-warning">
  
     
        <div class="col-md-8">
         
     <input  class="form-control" id="address" type="text" value="" placeholder="Bir yer yazınız!" />
     </div>
    
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="Ara" onClick="codeAddress()"/>
      </div>

  </div>
  
  

 <div id="map_canvas"></div>

  
  
    <div class="latlng-map alert alert-warning">
    
          <div class="form-group">
          
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                     <label for="lat">Enlem</label>
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lat" placeholder="Enlem" value="" />
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <label for="lng">Boylam</label>
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lng" placeholder="Boylam" value="" />
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                     <label for="zoom">Zoom</label>
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="zoom" placeholder="Zoom" value="" />
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                     <label for="kaydet"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
      <input class="btn btn-success form-control" id="kaydet" type="button" value="Kaydet" />
                    </div>
          </div>
  
   </div>
  
</form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

i add my external file here , this code is working well in my website but it is not working in this snippet, but all of my codes are here, there are no extra codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current zoom of the map by calling `map.getZoom()`

Comment: where can i put this?

Comment: Where do you want to get the zoom level of the map?

Comment: Thanks a lot i made it.